# Find out hyperlinks in HTML response using C without external libraries

Tags: html, c, parsing

I need to find out all the hyperlinks in the form of `<a href="xxxxxx">` in a HTML response without using external libraries. Hence, I use `strtok(message, " \n<>")` to split response into pieces. If the last piece is `a` and the current piece start with `href`, we find one link. However, the code does not perform well, producing memory problem.

VS code keeps popping up messages with text like this:

> Unable to open 'strlen.S': Unable to read file '/build/glibc-S7Ft5T/glibc-2.23/sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file '/build/glibc-S7Ft5T/glibc-2.23/sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S').

And in the terminal, it prints out:

> [1] + Done                       "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-fjtfcdmp.4qw" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-hlygokwk.gwa"

Here is my code:

```
// Omit the sending and receiving part
//
if(recv(tcpSocket, response_buf, sizeof(response_buf), 0) < 0){
        printf("Error with recv()\n");
    }
else {
        printf("Successfully receive response\n");
        // printf("Message received:\n %s\n", response_buf);
}
printf("===============================\n");
char * const dupstr = strdup(response_buf);
char* token = NULL;
token =  strtok(dupstr, " \n<>");

char last_token[2000];
char token_head[1000];
char a[] = "a";
char href[] = "href=";
while (token != 0) {
    strcpy(last_token, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " \n<>");
    if(strcmp(last_token, a) == 0){
        size_t len = strlen(token);
        if(len>5){
            strncpy(token_head, token, 5);
            if(strcmp(token_head, href)== 0){
                printf("%s\n", token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HTML is not trivial to parse. You really need to use a pre-existing HTML parsing library.

Comment: This has nothing to do with socket programming but is solely about extracting information from strings - no matter if the string comes from a socket, a file or whatever. I've edited title and tags to reflect this.

Comment: Why do you think does the error message point to memory problems?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to single step while debugging, and you try to step into library functions.

In your posted case you try to step into `strlen()`. Commonly the source files for such functions are not included in an installation. That's why your debugger tells you that it cannot find the source file.

If you are debugging your program with single stepping, use "next" to step over function calls of library functions.

Comment: Oh! This is something that I totally ignored. I will definitely deep into it. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I can see is with your code not properly checking the return value of `strtok`.
You only check the value of `token` at the begin of the loop, but then call `strtok`. If it returns `NULL`, you won't find out until after the rest of the loop has happened.

You want to move the `strtok` to the end of the loop like this

```
while (token != 0) {
    if(strcmp(last_token, a) == 0){
        size_t len = strlen(token);
        if(len>5){
            strncpy(token_head, token, 5);
            if(strcmp(token_head, href)== 0){
                printf("%s\n", token);
            }
        }

    }
    strcpy(last_token, token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " \n<>");
}
```

...so that the check actually does what it is meant to do.

Or an alternative way of doing the loop is to use a `for` loop

```
for(token = strtok(dupstr, " \n<>"); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " \n<>")) {
    if(strcmp(last_token, a) == 0){
        size_t len = strlen(token);
        if(len>5){
            strncpy(token_head, token, 5);
            if(strcmp(token_head, href)== 0){
                printf("%s\n", token);
            }
        }
    strcpy(last_token, token);
    }
```

Either way, you do need to properly initialise `last_token` as until that call to `strcpy` it could contain anything.

You also don't ever free `dupstr`. Whilst it isn't an issue at the moment since it'll be handled when the code exits, it is always a good habit to get into adding the corresponding call to `free` whenever you allocate memory.